# debug Pycharm code using console function call

Tags: python, pycharm, console, ide

Quick (hopefully) question on debugging in pycharm.
I have a large body of code in Pycharm that will be very tricky to debug by initiating the code as intended (via bash function).
What I need to do is to be able to call a specific function with a specific argument from the Pycharm console, and debug the code from there.
Firstly, is this possible? Assume I can't add any code to the main() function.
Secondly, could I get some pointers on how to call a function from the console?

When trying a simple function call with argument from the console, but I'm getting a "name not defined" error. So i try to import the module (from MyModuleName import all) but getting a module not found error. The Run/Debug configuration is set to 'Current File' which is the file I'm looking at in the code window, where the functions are defined.